# Delete build definitions in TFS via API

Tags: api, build

When creating TFS build definitions via the API, I need to first delete, if the definition pre-exists:

```cs
if (BuildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(teamProject).Any(d => d.Name == buildDefinitionName))
{
    buildDefinition = BuildServer.GetBuildDefinition(teamProject, buildDefinitionName);
    var builds = BuildServer.QueryBuilds(buildDefinition);
    if (builds != null && builds.Any())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("delete {0} builds for build definition: {1}", builds.Count(), buildDefinition.Name);
        BuildServer.DeleteBuilds(builds);
    }
    if (buildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings.Any())
    {
        var mappings = buildDefinition.Workspace.Mappings.Select(m => m.ServerItem).ToArray();
        foreach (var mapping in mappings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("remove workspace mapping: {0}", mapping);
            buildDefinition.Workspace.RemoveMapping(mapping);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("delete build definition: {0}", buildDefinition.Name);
    BuildServer.DeleteBuildDefinitions(new[] { buildDefinition });
}
```

This works as does the subsequent:

```cs
buildDefinition = BuildServer.CreateBuildDefinition(teamProject);
buildDefinition.Name = buildDefinitionName;
```

However, when the first build gets run, it throws an error about conflicting workspaces:

```
Exception Message: Unable to create the workspace 'some-new-workspace' due to a mapping conflict. You may need to manually delete an old workspace. You can get a list of workspaces on a computer with the command 'tf workspaces /computer:%COMPUTERNAME%'.
Details: The path C:\some-path is already mapped in workspace some-old-workspace. (type MappingConflictException)
```

As you can see in the first snippet, my attempt to delete workspaces with `.Workspace.RemoveMapping()`, has no effect. The workspaces still exist on the build controller. I can delete them manually but they really should get deleted when I delete the build definition. Is there some other `DeleteWorkspace()` mechanism in the API?

A more complete code gist is here: https://gist.github.com/grenade/cce374cb4e27e366bc5b

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the reason it's complicated is that the owner of the various workspaces created by the build could be some other user (that the build agent runs under).
I found a way to do it by relying on the previous build definition id which is used in the workspace naming convention `[build definition id]_[build agent id]_[workspace host]`:

```cs
var workspaceNamePrefix = string.Concat(buildDefinition.Id, '_');
var workSpaces = VersionControlServer.QueryWorkspaces(null, null, null).Where(w => w.Name.StartsWith(workspaceNamePrefix)).ToArray();
for (var i = workSpaces.Count() - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    try
    {
        workSpaces[i].Delete();
        Console.WriteLine("delete workspace: {0}", workSpaces[i].Name);
    }
    catch (ResourceAccessException rae)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(rae.Message);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("workspace needs to be deleted by an administrator using the following command:");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("tf workspace /delete {0};{1}", workSpaces[i].Name, workSpaces[i].OwnerName);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

I have updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/grenade/cce374cb4e27e366bc5b